# FreeRTOS Mutex multiple task with same priority

Tags: multithreading, freertos, stm32f4

I'm having some problems with FreeRTOS binary mutex. On my aplication there are multiple threads (tasks) with the same priority, two of these access to file I/O functions that are within mutex take and mutex release.

Depending on some timings one task is doing starvation to the other. Is that possible?

FreeRTOS take into account how many time is a task waiting for a resource?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing file I/O from within a critical section?  That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: to be multi-thread safe.

Comment: There are other ways to be thread safe.  The best way to avoid starvation is to keep your mutexes as small as possible:  Don't do anything that takes more than a few CPU cycles, and don't do anything that could _block_ the caller (e.g., don't do file I/O).   The best way to keep I/O thread safe is to only let one thread access any particular device.  I don't know what storage device your program talks to, but it probably has just one "port" or "interface," so there's no _performance_ reason to have more than one thread talk to it.  It's just a matter of how you choose to organize your program.

Comment: You can always force context switch with taskYIELD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the mutex in tight loops in multiple tasks?  If so then there is a logical reason why one task might hold the mutex for longer than you think.  If tasks A and B have the same priority, A is holding the mutex and B is waiting for the mutex, then a context switch won't occur when A gives the mutex back because B has the same priority as A (it would occur if B had a higher priority, but it would be a breach of the scheduling algorithm and risk task thrashing if a task switch occurred to an equal priority task).  There, if A is in a loop, gives the mutex back, then immediately takes it again, every time B attempts to take the mutex it will find A is still holding the mutex so, if B is also in a loop, it will block on the mutex again.  This scenario is easy to fix - but suggest you read the chapter that describes this in the freely available book:  http://www.freertos.org/Documentation/RTOS_book.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was a case where the SD card was full and the retry attemps made the scenario that you describes. I fix that with a delay of 1 ms on retries. A taskYield after de mutex release will fix the problem too, but in my case a delay is more cleaner I think. Is this behaviour normal on OSs? I was thinking that when an a call of mutex take is made then the OS will check which task were waiting for more time.

Comment: @jabella you are correct, if two tasks are the same priority the task waiting the longest should get scheduled next. To do this check the settings `configUSETIMESLICING` and `configUSE_PREEMPTION ` in your config file. Here's more information https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/May_2017/freertos_Processing_time_between_tasks_with_the_same_priority_30fbd897j.html